Integrate bivariate normal distribution over a polygon
Let $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,I_2)$, with $I_2\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ being the identity. I want to integrate its probability density function over a polygon $P$ whose (ordered) vertices are $\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. For my application, I don't need to solve it exactly, but I need to be efficient (I need to run it a bunch of times on limited hardware). In formulae, I want to solve:
\begin{equation}
 \int_{P}\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right)dx\,dy:= \int_{P}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
\end{equation}
I don't see how to solve this directly, and numerical approaches are too slow/heavy. However, given the structure of $P$, trying to apply Green's theorem is tempting. We can parametrize the boundary of $P$ as a set of curves $s_i:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $i = 1,\dots,n$, defined by:
\begin{equation}
 s_i(t) = p_i + t(p_{i+1}-p_i),
\end{equation}
where we identify $p_{n+1} = p_1$. Thus, by choosing, for instance, $M(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2})\mathrm{erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$ (where $\mathrm{erf}$ is the error function), we get that:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
 &\int_P f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \oint_{\partial P}M(x,y)dy = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(y_{i+1}-y_i)\int_{0}^{1}M(s_i(t))dt\right] = \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[(y_{i+1}-y_i)\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left(-\frac{(y_i + t(y_{i+1}-y_i))^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{x_i + t(x_{i+1}-x_i)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)dt\right],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with $p_i = (x_i,y_i)$ (i.e., they are constants). This is were I got stuck. I tried to integrate $M(s_i(t))$ by parts, but my attempts were fruitless.
Even though the performance is better, I'd really love to avoid having to numerically approximate these integrals. Does anyone have ideas on how to improve my derivation? I'm open to any suggestion (e.g., approximating $M(s_i(t))$ with simpler functions, changing my choice of functions for Green's theorem or taking a different approach altogether, etc.). Thank you!
